# can't download from composer on linux OS

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, mpdf, lampp

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for kreait/firebase-php 4.35 -> satisfiable by kreait/firebase-php[4.35.0].
    - kreait/firebase-php 4.35.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
```

You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Comment: its asking you to install `mbstring`, its a requirement for that package, you have php: ^7.2
ext-ctype
ext-json
ext-openssl installed but missing ext-mbstring

Comment: `the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.` Suggest you install the mbstring PHP Extension [See here for assist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491629/how-to-install-php-mbstring-extension-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is asking you to install the module mbstring if you are using ubuntu

try this

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

Comment: Problem 1
    - mpdf/mpdf v8.0.5 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - mpdf/mpdf v8.0.4 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - mpdf/mpdf v8.0.3 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - mpdf/mpdf v8.0.2 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - mpdf/mpdf v8.0.1 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing

Comment: install ext-gd module like that `sudo apt-get install php-gd`

Comment: can you please choose this answer as the right answer